# Logback is not writing specific log file on the Linux server

Tags: maven, tomcat, logback

I am using Logback API to log java based application and giving following path to create files, but on VPS server it's not creating file. Same config is working fine on my local machine. Please check if you can help, Is this issue related to folder and file write permission. I have given

chmod 777 permission to the following log folder, but still no luck. Please help.

No tack trace 
/root/apps/myservice/logs

No stack trace.

I have installed Tomcat 8 instance on this folder - /root/apps/authservice/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/logs

Is it the issue of write restriction of Tomcat to write on this logs folder
/on CentoS Linux machine? I have root user permission and Tomcat also has root user with all 777 permission from top root to nested foldler- I have installed Tomcat 8 instance on this folder - /root/apps/authservice/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/logs

Will Tomcat which u have installed on /usr/local/tomcat8/logs/ file write permission is same? Do I need to install Tomcat usr/local folder. Is it the issue of access rights of 
/root and /local access permission on CentoS Linux machine?

```
<property name="DEV_HOME" value="/root/apps/logs" />

<appender name="FILE-AUDIT"     class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${DEV_HOME}/myapp.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/myapp.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <!-- or whenever the file size reaches the max -->
            <maxFileSize>${rolling.file.max.size}</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <maxHistory>${rolling.file.max.history}</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>${rolling.file.encoder.pattern}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the Gremlins form the Flux Capacitor? :) - Just joking, but you need to add information to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  (stack traces, ls with permissions, logback configuration, where the logback file is located)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got solution of own issues and posting solution for others and save their 2 days of effort :)

Issue is related to conflict between log4j and Logback, when we migrate from old log4j to Logback. You need to exclude lo4j dependencies from existing dependencies by running this command:

$ mvn dependency:tree

= >Add these jars only for logging using SLF4j and Logback>

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${version.slf4j}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${version.logback}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${version.slf4j}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```